# Hyperledger Fabric network - using JAVA sdk - ERROR while creating channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

### Environment:

- MacOS : 10.13.6
- Golang : 1.11.8
- Hyperledger Fabric : 1.4
- Java : 1.8

### Description:

I try to run an [official JavaSDK Fabric app example](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk).

I can deploy and run the app normally with the default configuration.
Then I make some changes in `configtx.yaml` (just some rules about generating blocks) and generate the binary tool `configtxgen`, then I use:

- `./configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock genesis.block`
- `./configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx channel.tx -channelID mychannel`

commands to regenerate `channel.tx` and `genesis.block`.

I use these new files to start the fabric network, and follow the steps of [this page](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk), but I get the following error while creating channel:

```
*org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel mychannel, send transaction failed on orderer OrdererClient{id: 4, channel: mychannel, name: orderer.example.com, url: grpc://localhost:7050}. Reason: Channel mychannel orderer orderer.example.com status returned failure code 400 (BAD_REQUEST) during orderer next
    
Caused by: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel mychannel orderer orderer.example.com status returned failure code 400 (BAD_REQUEST) during orderer next*
```

The logs of orderer container say:

```
2020-08-26 10:25:33.469 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 009 [channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.0.1:56440 because of error: error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: attempted to set key [Value]  /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/AnchorPeers to version 1, but key does not exist
```

[image]

Anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your Anchor peers too like they said on script.

```
cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
mkdir config
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./config/genesis.block
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/channel.tx -channelID mychannel
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./config/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP
```

You can find details on [build.sh](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk/blob/master/network/build.sh) script and have to uncomment out those lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still get this error after running the script. I doubt that if sth wrong with configtxgen?

Comment: Such as sth like version issue?

Comment: Yeah, that might be an issue. You can fix this from here with Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.1 network:   https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html